# Python TypeError: CreateAccount() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, oop

I created this terminal app a while ago and it was working, but I haven't touched in a while and I just opened it back up and I can't figure out what this error is and why I'm having it. It's happening during the account creation part of my program. I tried a couple things out but I'm still not sure what's going on.

```
**TypeError: CreateAccount() missing 1 required positional argument**
```

**main.py**

```
from Account import Account
from Transaction import Transaction
from enum import Enum
from fcp import CreateAccount




#variables and lists needed for program
new_accounts = []

#do no tneed, just put the balance of 0 straight into the factory class attribute 
#balance = 0

user_name = []

Transactions = []


account_number = 0






#***Functions for switch statements***
def create_user():
    global new_accounts
    global account_number 

    active_create_account = False


    new_username = input("\n\nCreate a username:")


    email = input("Write your email: ")

    account_number +=1
    print(account_number)


# append the createaccount call straight into new_accounts.append
    new_accounts.append(CreateAccount(user_name,email, int(input('Choose 1 for Checkings or 2 for Savings:  ')), 0, 0))
    active_create_account = True
    for i in new_accounts:
    if account_number == i.account_number:
        i.new_account_creation()

account_search_balance = True



    if account_search_balance == False:
            print("\nThat account does not exist. Please re-enter option 5 and try again.")
            main()
```

**fcp.py**

```
from Account import Account 
from Transaction import Transaction


#BLANK CLASS TEMPLATE




def CreateAccount(self,user_name,email,account_type,balance,account_number):
            account_number +=1
            if (account_type == 1): return CreateCheckingAccount(user_name,email,1,balance,account_number)
            if (account_type == 2): return CreateSavingsAccount(user_name,email,2,balance,account_number)
            else:
             return CreatAccount(user_name,email, int(input('Choose 1 for Checkings or 2 for Savings:  ')),balance,account_number)


def CreateCheckingAccount(self,user_name,email,account_type,balance,account_number):
            return Account(user_name, email,'Checking',balance,account_number)


def CreateSavingsAccount(self,user_name,email,account_type,balance,account_number):
            return Account(user_name, email,'Savings',balance,account_number)
```

**transaction.py**

```
import datetime





class Transaction():



    def __init__(self,account_number,type_of_transaction,old_balance,new_balance,date = datetime.datetime.now()):

            self.account_number = account_number
            self.type_of_transaction = type_of_transaction
            self.old_balance = old_balance
            self.new_balance = new_balance
            self.date = datetime.datetime.now()





    def to_string(self):

        print("\nThe account number is: " + str(self.account_number) + "\nThe type of transaction is: " + self.type_of_transaction + "\nThe old balance was: " + str(self.old_balance) + "\nThe new balance is: " + str(self.new_balance) + "\nThe date of the transaction was: " + str(self.date))

    def print_date(self):

            print(str(self.date))
```

**Account.py**

```
class Account(object):

    def __init__(self,user_name,email,account_type,balance,account_number):


        self.user_name = user_name
        self.email = email
        self.account_type = account_type
        self.balance = balance
        self.account_number = account_number



    def print_balance(self):

        print("\nAccount bala is "+ str(self.balance))
        return 

    def new_balance(self):
        print("\nThe new account balance is: " + str(self.balance))


    def to_string(self):

        print("\nUsername: " + self.user_name + "\n\nEmail: " + self.email + "\n\nAccount type: " + (self.account_type) + 
            "\n\nYour account balance is:" + str(self.balance) +"\n\nAccount number: " + (self.account_number))

    def new_account_creation(self):

        print("\nCongragulations on your new account! Below is the info:\nUsername: " + self.user_name + "\nEmail: " + self.email + "\nAccount type: " + self.account_type + 
            "\nYour account balance is:" + str(self.balance) +"\nAccount number: " + str(self.account_number)+ " <--- Do NOT forget this number")

    def Deposit(self):


        deposit = int(input("\nHow much would you like to deposit?: "))
        self.balance += deposit 


    def withdraw(self,withdraw):

        self.balance -= withdraw
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should initiate the class object that contains createAccount() method before invoke.

```
class TestClass:
        def __init__(self):
            print("in init")
        def createAccount(self, ...):
            print("in Test Func")

testInstance = TestClass()
testInstance.createAccount(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though your method definition requires `self` as an argument but `CreateAccount` is not in a class. Therefore it is not required.

(remove `self` in the required arguments)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear, even though you left out the rest of the error message and failed to minimize your code: your function profile requires a `self` argument that the call didn't bother to provide.  Since you used the name `self`, it seems as if you might want to create a class -- but you didn't do that with the function, nor with the call.

If a class is, indeed, what you want, then please return to your tutorial on `class` to make sure you implement all of the right items.